# How to know what kind of directory listing style the FTP server is using?

Tags: ftp, directory-listing

I have to create my own FTP client. I found there are two kinds of directory listing styles a FTP server might use, UNIX and MS-DOS.

Is there a way that I can send an message to FTP server, to ask what kind of directory it is using?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org) to connect to an Unix server. you will see server responses as below example.

```
Response:    IDLE
Response:    MDTM
Response:    SIZE
Response:    REST STREAM
Response:    MLST type*;size*;sizd*;modify*;UNIX.mode*;UNIX.uid*;UNIX.gid*;unique*;
Response:    MLSD
Response:    AUTH TLS
Response:    PBSZ
Response:    PROT
Response:    ESTA
Response:    PASV
Response:    EPSV
Response:    SPSV
Response:    ESTP
```

Note the text **UNIX.mode**. It says server lists file in Unix mode. You can test the same with a Windows server too.